Android - Error while creating a jetpack compose project on Android Studio
I'm now using this version of android studio:
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1
Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11709847, built on April 12, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0--11572160 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.experimental.ui=true

Once I create an Jetpack Compose project, it inputs the following error on the sync part of the project:
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Github Compose'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:84)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$500(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:407)

...

    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.operations.MultipleBuildOperationFailures: A build operation failed.
    Could not read workspace metadata from C:\Users\Leona\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\5aea79953a1eab868b13bfb048843e5d\metadata.bin
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue.markFinished(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue.lambda$waitForWorkToComplete$0(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:319)
...

    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not read workspace metadata from C:\Users\Leona\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\5aea79953a1eab868b13bfb048843e5d\metadata.bin
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.history.impl.DefaultImmutableWorkspaceMetadataStore.loadWorkspaceMetadata(DefaultImmutableWorkspaceMetadataStore.java:63)

...

    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Leona\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\5aea79953a1eab868b13bfb048843e5d\metadata.bin (O sistema n�o pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.history.impl.DefaultImmutableWorkspaceMetadataStore.loadWorkspaceMetadata(DefaultImmutableWorkspaceMetadataStore.java:45)
    ... 33 more


CONFIGURE FAILED in 1s

C:\Users\Leona\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\5aea79953a1eab868b13bfb048843e5d\metadata.bin (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)

PS: (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado) means The system cannot find the given file.

Have you tried removing the folder C:\Users\Leona\.gradle\caches? It stores the downloaded gradle dependencies and some other stuff. It will get recreated on your next gradle build and downloads everything that's needed. That might take some time.

@Leviathan it worked. Do you mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it?

Similar problem hit me today. Upgrading my dependencies fixed it. Clearing my cache as suggested below didn't  do anything. I was missing - Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\caches\transforms-4\fa5d55bd018883fd5590eba876e1f863\metadata.bin

Your Gradle cache probably got corrupted. Locate it in your user profile (C:\Users\Leona\.gradle\caches) and delete it. Among others it contains the downloaded gradle dependencies and will get recreated on your next gradle build when everything that's needed will be downloaded again.
Be aware that this can take some time, depending on your connection speed. Also keep in mind that the gradle cache is shared with all gradle builds that are done by this windows user so it's not just your current project that is affected by needing its dependencies downloaded again.
